# What is this flat dry stick-like leaf that rattles?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I googled those terms but came up empty, here are three photos with a ruler for scale:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The hole and scratches are my dog's teeth, so as you can tell, it is strong yet not brittle. When you shake it, it rattles, like maybe there are seeds in there.

It's from a public irrigated park in a Northern Hemisphere hot desert climate (BWh) region, and I picked it up today, so spring time if that will help.

My dog is usually the one to find it, and we play fetch with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this a seed-pod from an [Inga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inga) or [Delonix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix) plant.

Inga are native to South America, while Delonix are native to Madagascar. But they've been introduced to other places and I've seen similar plants in the northern hemisphere. Inda and Delonix are both members of the subfamily [*Caesalpinioideae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesalpinioideae). I found the name by searching for "seed pod shaker". Sometimes you just need to know what terms to google.

Shown in the image below is pacay, or [*Inga feuillei*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inga_feuillei).

[image: pacay]

But your pod could also be from the flame tree, [*Delonix regia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix_regia).

[image: flame tree]

Answer (score 4):

It is a large seed pod of a leguminous tree (Fabaceae family).  This is one of the largest plant families that there is, so it is impossible to identify the species exactly without more information.  Many trees of this family are drought (desert) tolerant as you mention BWh region of northern hemisphere. The seed pod in your photo looks very much like Delonix regia. A couple of links are below.

https://garden.org/plants/photo/125733/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delonix_regia